# How to setup custom package install location in yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, bower, yarnpkg

I run a project and have decided to switch from using bower to using yarnpkg. However, I would like to install the modules at a custom location rather than at the default `node_modules/`. In bower, currently I am achieving this functionality in bower by putting the following in the `.bowerrc`:

```
{
    "directory": "./public/lib"
}
```

Is this kind of installation of packages at custom locations possible in yarnpkg? If yes, how can I do it? I have looked for such configuration options in the official documentation but have had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to specify a different directory for local installs. I think it's related to an underlying node/npm issue, specifically [this github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/775).